# ASP.NET MVC upload file with ajax with multiple parametrs

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to upload a file from my file input through ajax with multiple parameters through an ASP.NET MVC controller and I am getting an error.
Save file from input to variable data2.

```
var data2 = new FormData();
var files;

var loadFile = function (event) {
     files = $("#upload").get(0).files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        data2.append("MyImages", files[0]);
    }
};
```

Send data with ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/Adot/UploadAdopt",
        type: "POST",
        data: { ForUpload:data2,
                 Title:"New name"},
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadAdopt(HttpPostedFileBase ForUpload, string Title)
{
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/image/adopts"), Path.GetFileName(ForUpload.FileName));
        ForUpload.SaveAs(path);
        return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get? Can you share the html as well.

Comment: @Jasen I have error 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation'

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52416731/2030565

Comment: This solved my problem. But I still didn't get it, why I should use append and can't use multiple data ajax parametrs and simply pass a file type as a parametr into controller, as I usualy do with any other data types(string, int, bool)?

Comment: When you want to send file plus an additional payload, we use `multipart/form-data`. The `FormData` interface provides an easy way to construct this type of request. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData