# jquery pass null to action controller parameter even value not null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have Action method in controller as below

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string foldername)
        {
            string folderpath = "~/UploadedDoc/" + foldername;

            string folder = Server.MapPath(folderpath);
            if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
            }

            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(folderpath), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(filePath);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

And in View I send value to that Action method:

```
<div><input type="text" id="txtfolderName" /></div>
<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Upload1", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>

        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success" />
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
}
```

Jquery to call Action method:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {



            //upload
            var fileUpload = $("#file").get(0);
            var file = fileUpload.files;


            $.post("/Upload1/UploadFile", { "file": file, "foldername": $("#txtfolderName").val() }, function (data) {
                alert("final folder: " + data);
            });


        });
    </script>
```

I use alert to show value of  `$("#txtfolderName").val()` in jQuery not null,
but when call "foldername" parameter in controller, it pass null to this parameter

I don't understand Jquery always send null to parameter of action in controller?

I did anything wrong?
Can you help me?

#Tried to change as below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Upload1", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        <br />
        <div><input type="text" id="txtfolderName" /></div>
        <br />
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
        <br />

        <input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success" />
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
}

 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnUpload").click(function () {
            //upload
            var fileUpload = $("#file").get(0);
            var file = fileUpload.files;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Upload1/UploadFile",
                contentType: Text,
                data: { file: file, foldername: $("#txtfolderName").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("There was error uploading files!");
                }
            });                
        });
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Please include code as text, not as images.

Comment: Your action is `UploadFile1` but you're calling `UploadFile`

Comment: @freedomn-m please refer to this cose

Comment: @freedomn-m i adjusted my code to simple to show to you, so it wrong name.  But even i change Action name to "UploadFile ". It also not work. i don't understand why "foldername" in action method always get null

Comment: @NathanDang Are you getting file in the controller?? My question is this, that are you getting any data on the controller or not?

Comment: @Developer : my job is to create a folder dynamically based on passed value of "foldername". After that i will upload files to this folder. But when i input foldername value in view and click upload, then all files uploaded to root folder "~/UploadedDoc/". Because values of "foldername" in controller got null. and i don't understand why

Comment: @NathanDang Where is this field "$("#txtfolderName")"

Comment: @Developer it was hidden by the code formatting - I've updated to show it

Comment: @Developer can you help to check it?

Comment: @NathanDang Oky, wait checking in some mins

Comment: Most likely issue: Your `$.post` is in the `doc.ready` so it occurs before the user has a chance to fill in txtfolderName

Comment: Other likely issue: Your `btnUpload` is `type=submit` so will submit everything *inside the form* - without an ajax $.post request as there's no click handler / form submit handler.  Your `txtfolderName` is *not* inside the `<form>` so will not be submitted via the form post (caused by the button submit).

Comment: Fixes: change btnUpload to `type='button'` so it doesn't submit the form.  and/or move txtfolderName inside the `@using Html.BeginForm` and/or add a click handler to the button (or form submit event) to use your ajax instead of the form submit.

Comment: @freedomn-m: I tried move txtfolderName into a form, then use ajax click handle but value of foldename parameter still NULL

Comment: From your other comments, it sounds like you want to:  remove `form` (and Razor version) completely, just for your own sanity / change button to `type='button'` / change the code in your doc.ready to wrap it in a button.click event handler.

Comment: @freedomn-m: Thank for supporting alot. But i still can not solve. I tried as "#Tried to change as below:" in above content. because code is long so i can not write in comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax.BeginForm instead of your $.post. First install the package from nuget package manager "Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax". Then you need to include the reference of unobtrusive ajax which will be installed after the nuget package.

`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>`

You also move your foldername input inside the form and name it "foldername". Then change you code like below:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="foldername" id="foldername" value="MyTest" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>

            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success" />
            @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
    }
```

Then delete all your  code. It should work.

Comment: how to pass parameters to action method controller in your way?

Comment: Do you need more parameters? You need to include the input control inside the Form and provide them "name" property. Whatever the name you will give to the element, it will get the value automatically. For example if you include one more <input name="test" id="test" /> then it will be automatically get the value by name "test"

Comment: I followed your guide and it worked. but in this way, value of input tag will auto pass to parameters in controller and they're matching by name. So how about if i have to cooking data of input tag, i mean pre-processing its value before send this value to parameter in controller? how to send parameter in this case?

Comment: You need to change the code for that. Can you go through to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416591/send-file-and-text-parameters-using-ajax-on-mvc