# Save file and other values to database (file is saved but other values are not saved)

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core

In the ASP.NET Core MVC project, I am saving values such as the file and the user who added the file, taskId in the table named TaskListAttachment. I am using ajax for this. The file is added to the database, but the AddUserId and TaskId columns are saved as 0.

Controller.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddFile(IFormFile file, TaskListAttachment taskListAttachment)
{
    if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.Combine("wwwroot/files", Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
        using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            file.CopyTo(stream);
        }
        taskListAttachment.FileName = file.FileName;
        taskListAttachment.ContentType = file.ContentType;
        taskListAttachment.Data = new byte[file.Length];
        taskListAttachment.AddDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        taskListAttachment.FilePath = fileName;
        taskListAttachmentManager.itemAdd(taskListAttachment);
        var addValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(taskListAttachment);
        return Json(addValue);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(null);
    }
}
```

cshtml side

```
@using EntityLayer.Concrete;

@model TaskListViewModel;

<form method="post" id="fileUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div id="addUserId" data-user-id="@Model.TaskLists.UserAssigned?.Id"></div>
<div id="taskId" data-task-id="@Model.TaskLists.TaskID"></div>

<label class="form-label">Dosya Ekle</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="fileInput" class="form-control" />
<button id="uploadButton" class="btn mb-1 waves-effect waves-light btn-light-primary text-primary" type="button">Upload</button>
</form>

<script>
    $("#uploadButton").click(function () {
        var addUserId = $("#addUserId").data("user-id");
        var taskId = $("#taskId").data("task-id");
        console.log(addUserId);
        console.log(taskId);
        var model = {
            AddUserId: addUserId,
            TaskId: taskId,
        };
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("model.AddUserId", addUserId);
        formData.append("model.TaskId", taskId);
        formData.append("file", $("#fileInput")[0].files[0]);
        console.log(formData);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/TaskList/AddFile/",
            type: "Post",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    alert(result.message);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I see addUserId and taskId values in the console but they are sent to the database as 0.

Comment: You might try just changing them from `"model.` to `"taskListAttachment.`, since that's the name of your argument on the server side. I would set `contentType` to "multipart/form-data" rather than false also.

Comment: I updated it as you said. There was no change, it still sends the value as 0

Comment: Hi, @gkmnada! Did you check this question: (***`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416591/send-file-and-text-parameters-using-ajax-on-mvc`***)?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez thank you very much, I found the solution in the post you shared.